# Is this equality about derivative of a polynomial valid?

Tags: polynomials

Why is $\left(x^2-1\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2-1\right)^n = 2nx\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}$? This is in a textbook and says that its proof is left as an exercise. It seems to be a difficult identity.

I believe this should just be $\left(x^2-1\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2-1\right)^n = 2nx\left(x^2-1\right)^{n}$ by simple differentiation.

Which is true?

Comment: You are right, the book is wrong.

Comment: Let $f=x^2-1$.Then $( f^n)'=nf^{n-1}f'$.

Comment: *why* is the book multiplying the derivative by $(x^2 - 1)$?  Yes, the derivative should be to power n - 1 and multiplying by $(x^2 - 1)$ would make the power n.

Comment: "Let $f=x^2−1$. Then $(f^n)′=nf^{n−1}f′$."  Yes but $f*(f^n)′=f*nf^{n−1}f′ = nf^nf'$.  (gad I hope I formatted that right.)

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize what various commenters said, the chain rule tells us that
$$(f^n)'=nf^{n-1}f'.$$
If we let $f(x)=x^2-1$, we can see that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(x^2-1\right)^n\right]=n\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}(2x).$$
Multiplying both sides of the above equation by $x^2-1$, we have, as you correctly assumed:
$$\begin{align}
\left(x^2-1\right)\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(x^2-1\right)^n\right]&=\left(x^2-1\right)n\left(x^2-1\right)^{n-1}(2x)\\
&=2nx\left(x^2-1\right)^n
\end{align}$$